# I think my car has a steam problem

Tags: peugeot-207

This morning (temperature 5°C) it took 5 minutes of full power ventilation with engine on to get rid of the steam inside. Even when removing it manually with a sponge, somehow I could still not see through the windscreen.

Never had this problem with my Citroen before. Also my 207 is way warmer in general inside, I don't understand why.

Any tip about the steam on the windscreen?

Comment: using the sponge made things worse, how long did you wait before trying that?  Also 5 minutes seems about right for every vehicle I've ever owned, you have to wait for the vehicle to heat up some which doesn't happen quickly.

Comment: Is the peugeot a darker color (either interior or exterior) than the citroen?  That would explain why it's hotter inside.  It could just be better insulated as well.

Comment: There are loads of suggestions in this question - https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/72567/heavy-condensation-inside-car-during-winter-tried-multiple-things-but-no-resul

Comment: Did you have the AC on?

Answer (score 3):

Most modern cars engage A/C automatically when the windscreen defrost mode is on.  With the heat set on high and the A/C engaged, the system acts as a dehumidifier.  Set the heat at its highest position and check that the A/C is engaging when the defrost mode is active.  Depending on the car, you may see that the A/C is active by an LED on the control.  You may also year the compressor engage when you switch on the defrost mode.  You may have a problem with your A/C system if its not engaging.

Another possibility is too much moisture in the car to begin with.  For example, if the floor mats are very wet from tracking in mud and snow the last time you used it, it can take longer for the moisture to be removed from the air.  Ensuring that you are selecting outside air and not recirculating air will help.

If the car is older, other problems can be poorly fitting doors that leak water or drains at the base of the windscreen clogged with leaves and dirt leading to leaks. If you smell anti-freeze you could have a leaking heater core which will emit steam into the air you're trying to dry.

Comment: Welcome to the site Bryan.  Nice detail on this answer.  I will add that there is often a low-temperature cutoff switch on the A/C system that will prevent it from running in very cold outside temperatures so it will not _always_ come on with the defrost.